# Why this AutoMapper conversion fails?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

In the following automapper example I've to deal with some different kind of problem:

- property of the target class (`P`) which are themselves classes (i.e. `PContact`, `Bank`)
- lists (`new List<Bank>()`)
- wrapper class (`Wrapper` wraps `IDataRecord`)

What's wrong?

I would like to convert from an instance of a `IDataRecord` to an instance of class `P`.

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<IDataRecord, P>()
    .ConvertUsing(x => AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Wrapper, P>(new Wrapper(x)));

AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Wrapper, P>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.GetString("Nome")))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.LastName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.GetString("Cognome")))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Banks,
        opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Wrapper, List<Bank>>(src)));

AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Wrapper, PContact>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.StreetAddress, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.GetString("Indirizzo")))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Town, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.GetString("Città")))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Phone, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.GetString("Telefono")))

AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Wrapper, List<Bank>>()
    .ConvertUsing(x => new List<Bank>() { AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Wrapper, Bank>(x) });

AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Wrapper, Bank>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.AccountNumber, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.GetString("NumCC")))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.IBAN, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.GetString("IBAN")));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to the fact that AutoMapper has its own Mapper for the IDataReader so it's needed to do the following

```
public class AutomapperTypeAdapterFactory
        :ITypeAdapterFactory
    {
        public AutomapperTypeAdapterFactory()
        {
            //scan all assemblies finding Automapper Profile
            var profiles = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                                    .GetAssemblies()
                                    .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
                                    .Where(t => t.BaseType == typeof(Profile));

            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                foreach (var item in profiles)
                {
                    if (item.FullName != "AutoMapper.SelfProfiler`2")
                        cfg.AddProfile(Activator.CreateInstance(item) as Profile);
                } 
            });

            //===>>
            MapperRegistry.Mappers.Remove(MapperRegistry.Mappers.FirstOrDefault(x => x is DataReaderMapper));
        }
   }
```